# ObjectMapper can generate a list of invalid types (java8)

Tags: java, objectmapper

This is not so much a question of what's wrong with the code as it is, why does java allow this code to work?

Using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper it's possible to create a List populated with data types that should be invalid for the declared list.

I'm telling it to convert a `List<Potato>` into a `List<Potato>` and storing the result in `List<Tractor>`

```java
public class ObjectMapperExample {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Potato> potatoList = new ArrayList<>();
        //add a potato to the potatoList

        List<Tractor> tractorList = new ObjectMapper()
                .convertValue(potatoList, new TypeReference<List<Potato>>() {});
        //add another tractor to the tractorList

        System.out.println(tractorList.getClass());
        System.out.println(tractorList.toString());
        System.out.println(tractorList.get(1).getClass());
        System.out.println(tractorList.get(0).getClass());
    }
}
```

Potato.class

```java
public class Potato {
   // properties and getters/setters
}
```

Tractor.class

```java
public class Tractor {
   // properties and getters/setters
}
```

This code actually compiles and runs, up till you try to directly interact with the `Potato` object in the `tractorList`.  Resulting output...

> class java.util.ArrayList
>
> [Potato@20e2cbe0, Tractor@68be2bc2]
>
> class Tractor
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Potato cannot be cast to Tractor     at ObjectMapperExample.main(ObjectMapperExample.java:27)

So the question is, why does java still run this?  Shouldn't a `List<Tractor>` that has a `Potato` object as it's first element have thrown an exception somewhere?  It's throwing an exception when accessing the element directly, which makes sense, but how did it manage to create a List with incompatible object types to begin with?

Here's a screenshot of the actual run I did...
[image: Test run]

Answer (score 0):

Because the [ObjectMapper::convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference)) is bogus in how the generics were declared:

```
public <T> T convertValue(Object fromValue, TypeReference<?> toValueTypeRef) 
  throws IllegalArgumentException
public <T> T convertValue(Object fromValue, JavaType toValueType)
  throws IllegalArgumentException
```

There is no relation between `T` and `TypeReference<?>`: the compiler infer the real type of `T` by using the context, and since the context is:

```
List<Tractor> tractorList = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(potatoList, new TypeReference<List<Potato>>() {});
```

It tries to infer the type `T`: `List<Tractor>` matches and `TypeReference<List<Potato>>` matches `TypeReference<?>`: the `TypeReference` may be completely unrelated to the output type which is why it was able to create a list of `Potato`. And since the type erasure kicks in, this is possible in the virtual machine.

It seems the same apply for the method using `JavaType`.

The other using `Class<T>` would not apply in your case in your case because you can't do `List<Tractor>.class`.

[edit] if you wish to reproduce same kind of issues, then you can do that:

```
List<Potato> potatoes = asList(new Potato());
List<Tractor> tractors = badStuff(potatoes);

private static <T> T badStuff(Object value) {
  return (T) value; // should raise a warning due to the cast
}
```

`T` is inferred from the context and in that context, this would be `List<Tractor>`. Some compiler might choke on this (Javac may accept this while Eclipse Compiler won't and vice versa) and require to precise the type:

```
List<Tractor> tractors = MyType.<List<Tractor>>badStuff(potatoes);
```

If you wish to look more in depth, this would probably help: [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.  The question is not "how do i use ObjectMapper", it was "Why is it possible to build a List<> of objects that are of the incorrect type".

Comment: My answer is split into two parts: the first about type erasure, and why it fail in that case, and the second about use of  Jackson API: it fails to do so because `TypeReference` don't have sufficient information about the type of object in list.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's possible to create a List in java with incompatible types.

Comment: I would prefer an explanation that does not involve ObjectMapper.  I used it in my example only because I don't otherwise know how to replicate the issue (thus why I am asking here why it happens).  The final result is having a List with elements that do not conform to it's declared type.  If this can be recreated without ObjectMapper (which should be possible unless i'm mistaken) and explained why it's possible, that would satisfy my question.  If it's not possible to recreate this issue without ObjectMapper (which I doubt) then explain why.